# connect to docker postgresql from remote grafana

Tags: postgresql, docker, grafana

I have a linux virtual machine remotely on the cloud hosted at digitalocean, this machine has grafana installed. Locally I have docker and I launched a postgresql server with the following docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  
  timescale:
    image: timescale/timescaledb-ha:pg14-latest
    container_name: timescaledb
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - timescale-volume:/home/postgres/pgdata/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
    networks:
      - trade-net
    
networks:
  trade-net:
    external: true

volumes:
  timescale-volume:
    external: true
```

Upon checking my network with `network inspect trade-net` I get:

```
"IPv4Address": "172.22.0.3/16"
```

I would like to connect via grafana now to my postgresql docker container which has been launched from my local machine, the grafana options are the following ones:

[image]

I have tried to fill this with :

```
Host: 172.22.0.3:5432
Database: postgres
User: postgres Password: password
```

But the connection is never established.

One thing to note is that my `postgresql.conf` file has :

```
listen.addresses = '*'
```

Answer (score 1):

The IP address from the docker network is available only through your local PC.

To access your container remotely you need your computer's public IP address.

Try running

```
curl ifconfig.me
```

It will return your public IP.

---

You should also check your router's firewall, to make sure it allows connections to port 5432

Comment: I have tried my public IP address as a substitute for the docker IP address but it didn't work. my firewall is turned off